# Edittext that make selection on long click but do not show context menu?

Tags: android, android-edittext, onlongclicklistener

i want to provide custom handlers that cut,copy text.

Target on Longclick

1. Context Menu Should not appear.
2. Text could get selected with trackers ( or Draggers ).

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notetext);
    . . . .

    edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback()
    {
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });

  . . . .

}

@Override
public void onSupportActionModeStarted(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode) {
    super.onSupportActionModeStarted(mode);
    View v = new View(MainActivity.this);
    mode.setCustomView(v);
    mode.getMenu().clear();
    mode.getMenu().close();
    mode.finish();
}
```

Using above piece of code i am able to remove Select All, Cut, Copy and Paste.But Still it shows "Text Selection"

Below Image shows what is required.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you want to get rid of the ActionMode? and create your own??

you can override this and get notified when the default is about to be displayed

```
  @Override
  public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {     
    super.onSupportActionModeStarted(mode);
    //you can add your custom ui here
    mode.setCustomView(....);// it takes a view
}
```

if you want to close it then you call `mode.finish();` you can call it there to close if or finish it if you do not need it.

when it is about to die it calls this onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode)` the methods i have stated are for the support libraries, hope you know that.

The rest is cheese

Comment: Updated question. Please suggest something.

Comment: mode.finish() works but it is looking ugly , the menu comes and hides and whole view gets shaked,and  the selection is not retained

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have sorted this out. This solution perfectly works for me. First of all, you need to create the context menu background as follows

menuback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
      </shape>
    </item>
  </selector>
```

Then Create your Custom Menu as follows

mymenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/m" android:title=" " ></item>
  </menu>
```

Now add the following lines on your

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/menuback</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>

</resources>
```

And Finally set elevation of the actionbar to 0 and implement the ActionMode.CallBack as follows

```
       EditText editText=findViewById(R.id.ed);

    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenu().clear();
            MenuInflater inflater=mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu,menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });
```

Ta...da... Here is the Final Result

[image: screenshot]